# Analyze Bulk Data Stored in Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, psql, bigdata

I have large dataset stored in PSQL.

My table Schema Consist of :

- id,location_id,hotel_id -> INT
- check_in_date,checkout_date -> DATES
- adults,currency -> ENUM
- room_type,sub_room_type -> ENUM
- min_price,max_price -> INT

For beginning purpose, I need to get distribution of prices (0,10,25,50,75,100 percentile ) of all the hotels

I want to perform this task for analysis, so speed is not a problem. 
At first I though to transfer all data to AWS Redshift,perform the task and close it, but I was unable to estimate the cost.

I want to explore the multiple solution to this which are cost-effective.

Machine in Use: AWS db.t2.micro with 200 GB Allocated Space

Tables With Estimated Data Stored And Row Count
[image: Estimated Data Stored in Server]
Each Table has same schema with field types:
1 Primary Id, 3 Date Field, 4 Enum, 4 Price, 4 Integers

Comment: What aggregation? What query? Why are you "unable" to run it? You seem to have left out all the important bits.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for responding. I have updated the question

Comment: OK, so you don't have a query and want help writing one. What have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: @CraigRinger With reference to above schema, I am storing the price of each hotel within a checkin_date, checkout_date and inserted timestamp. I want to get the percentile distribution of prices of each hotel id. Since the table has millions of entry, I am unable to figure out the correct method to analyse my data

Comment: I have following doubts as well: 
1) I need to update multiple record ( On Avg 20 Records / Per User Request ) where each record has different condition. How to identify correct approach a. First Delete All the Records in the first query & then insert it b. Figure out the new upsert query of PSQL 9.5 - 
2) I have been creating new table with same schema when data size reaches certain threshold. Say 15 GB & 40 GB . How should i make decision if I should create small table or one bulk table ? 
3) How to analyse time series data in real time ?